# How to use in memory database with injected test with play java

Tags: java, playframework, guice, playframework-2.4

The [play documentation about functional tests in java](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaFunctionalTest) shows two modes

- using fakeApplication to specify a custom configuration (in memory database in the example)
- using dependency injection to configure the application

I would like to use dependency injection but I have to set custom configuration on application startup like the use of in memory database.

I cannot achieve to do that. I guess this has to be done in the guice builder but I don't know how.

Comment: Did you look at this? https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaTestingWithDatabases

Comment: this chapter is if you want to test with a database but without an application. I want to start an application with the in-memory database

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java/blob/master/test-app/test/be/objectify/deadbolt/java/test/controllers/subject/SubjectPresentMethodConstraintsTest.java#L44 - it might help get you started.

Comment: in your example you are not using DI neither DI setup process so I don't understand how it can helps me in my case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I am assuming you are using Guice for DI.*

The discussion on issue [4809](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4809) on the framework's github repo should help on answering your question.

I was able to make it work using one of the solutions on the issue:

```
       new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
            .configure((Map) Helpers.inMemoryDatabase())
            .in(Mode.TEST)         
            .build();
```